# download xlsx file to server using php

Tags: php, excel, curl

When I paste this link in browser, it downloads a .xlsx file and it opens correctly.
But when I try to download the file to server using curl, file_get_contents() or file_put_contents() it doesn't open and shows an error.

All I want to do is to download the file to my server.

```
$url = 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.xlsx", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```